# Database locked issue while Inserting in same table the Array of more than 1000 records by multiple client

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, thread-safety, ormlite-servicestack

I am facing the big issue. I have created the service stack web services in C# DotNet and Database is SQLite (v4.0.30319). My System hang / Database locked issue, some time SQlite database file also corrupted  while inserting/ updating the database table by number of clients (more than one connection). All are update the same table same time. Whle One is updating other try to connect than the system hang. I have tried all the ways but not able to resolve this issue.

How can I force that One One client can update the table at one time other clients can readonly mode.

My code as below

```
    public bool CreateAnother2(LTHR record)
    {
       public IDbConnection Db { get; private set; }

      OrmLiteConnectionFactory factory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source= C:/Database/db.sqlite;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True", ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance);

        try
        {
            using (Db = factory.OpenDbConnection())
            {
                using (var trans = Db.BeginTransaction()  
                {                         
                        // If no error insert data
                        var id = (int)Db.Insert(record, selectIdentity: true);
                        trans.Commit();
                        Db.Close();  
                        return true;                       
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Db.Close();  
            } 
        }
        finally
        {
            if (Db.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Db.Close();  
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite is not meant to be used concurrently by multiple clients. That is your application runnning on multiple machines, or multiple applications on the same machine accessing the same shared database-file.
There are other solutions for that use case. (think mysql, postgress, Sqlserver, Oracle ea.).

If your application uses multiple connections to the database from one application but on different threads make sure that you open the database in serialized mode.
https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. At this time very difficult to change the database Type. I am using multiple connections to the database from one application for this I have to implement serialized mode  sqlite3_threadsafe but I do not know how. I am not able to find the config option of Sqlite. 

I am using  ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Windows.dll, v4.0.40.0.

Comment: You don't have to implement serialized most, just make sure that the sqlite binaries are compiled with that flag